# Filling datamatrix contour to enable scanning

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a small etched datamatrix on a metal body which after some processing (in gray scale) results in the sample images. The resultant image is mostly good except for some area outside the module which share the same color as that within the module boundaries. What is the needed is to make only the area within module boundaries (white border) to be made white.

Tried Opencv morph opening followed by closing, but results are not great (decoding does not occur). Also tried Canny edge and fill contour,but that introduces noise. I could theoretically remove some contours but that would lead to inaccurate image as some contours (mostly black area) are housed within contours that need coloring, and would lead to inaccurate results (or no scan).

What should be the best way (requiring less images/hit-trial) to make this happen. The area within white boundaries will change (horizontal or vertical gaps) depending on the incident light angle.

```
// In Java, ZXing is being used to read the pre-processed image
// based on processed bytearray returned from native

// Native process, takes input 480x640 image, crops based on view finder 
// which is when we have a 213x213 sized image
cv::resize(img, img, Size(600, 600));

labelUtils.BrightnessAndContrastAuto(img, img);

// identify contour area of datamatrix and crop the selection
vector<Point> contourPoints;
getDataMatrixContour(img,contourPoints);
if (contourPoints.empty) {
   threshold(img, img, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
   return;
}
// get contour rect which has the code
Rect icRect = cv::boundingRect(contourPoints);
//            double scaleFactor = desiredWidth / icRect.width;

// resize bounding rect to have some padding area
LabelUtils::resizeRect(icRect, 1.2);

// make rect even, else cvtColor color fails for odd-sized images
if (icRect.width % 2 != 0)
   icRect.width += 1;
if (icRect.height % 2 != 0)
   icRect.height += 1;

// crop image to a (sub)scaled even size
labelUtils.submatImage(pImg, icRect);

int sigma = 2, threshold = 5, amount = 10;
sharpenForMetal(img, sigma, threshold, amount);

threshold(img, img, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
return;
```

[sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9N7H.png)
[image: sample 2]
[image: sample 3]

Comment: Could you clarify what your end-goal is? Preferably by showing an image where decoding does work. Also, "which after some processing (in gray scale) results in the sample images": please show the code of the preprocessing you've applied, and show the image before this preprocessing. It's often easier to reach a goal if one can take some steps back.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Have added code and overall processing details. The pre-processing happens in native while decoding occurs in Java using ZXing. Native takes a NV21 byte-array and after processing returns a byte-array, which is then passed to ZXing decoder.

Answer (score 0):

The loss of image clarity is due to use of resize instead of homography transformation. Resize results in loss image, while homography retains the details needed for further processing pipeline that I had.